# How to remove digit at the start of a file name?

Tags: regex

I want to remove digits at the start of a filename. For example:

```
atoms/01-headings/01-heading-level-01.html
```

to

```
atoms/headings/heading-level-01.html
```

I've build this regex `/(^\d+|(?=\/)\/\d+)[\-\.]/img` but it seem that the positive lookahead `(?=\/)` consume the `/` too.

How to not consume it ?

Here's my tests: https://regex101.com/r/hK0rZ2/5

Comment: That is for JavaScript, right? It is not the lookahead that consumes, the `\/` in `\/\d+` does.

Answer (score 1):

Search using this regex:

```
/(^|\/)\d+[.-]?/img
```

and replace by:

```
"$1"
```

Captured group #1 `(^|\/)` matches either start position or a `/` followed by 1 or more digits and an optional hyphen OR DOT. In replacement we `$1` as back reference of captured group #1.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK0rZ2/9)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the lookahead that consumes the slash, the `\/` in `\/\d+` does.

You can use

```
/(?:^|(\/))\d+[-.]/igm
```

And replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0yC0/3)

The regex matches:

- `(?:^|(\/))` - either the start of  a line (`^`) or a `/` symbol and will *capture* the `/` into Group 1 (we'll later restore it with a `$1` backreference)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[-.]` - either `-` or a `.` literally (since it is a character class, and the hyphen is at the beginning of it, no escaping is necessary).

```js
var re = /(?:^|(\/))\d+[-.]/img; 
var str = '01-heading-level-01.html\n02-heading-level-02.html\natoms/01-headings/01-heading-level-01.html\natoms/01-headings/01-heading-level-1.html\natoms/01-headings/02-heading-level-02.html\natoms/01-headings/02-heading-level-2.html\natoms/01-headings/01-heading-level-01/01-headings-level-01-red.html';
var result = str.replace(re, '$1');
document.body.innerHTML = result.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

Comment: It will add an extra `/` before `01-heading-level-01.html`

Comment: @anubhava: Which pattern? :)

Comment: You've edited it now however it is near similar to my answer now :)

Comment: No, it is not, mine has explanation why `/` is consumed with OP regex, demo, and the pattern is different. I see no point in capturing the start of a string, and the `-` or `.` are obligatory to match.